# When I try to predict with my model I get an Attribute error

Tags: linear-regression

After I've created my model using keras sequential, I tried to start predicting on a small sample to see if it would work however I get this error and I have no idea why.

> error : AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in () ----> 1 example_results
>   = model.predict(example_batch) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

The code for my model can be found here :

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mxRIx5ufVsA0ljdTpL0Ud0qm2y39eyGX

I've done it using this method before but it refuses to work this time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cell 10 of your notebook you write:

```
model = build_model() #Perfect
```

In cell 11 you write:

```
model = model.summary() #Uh oh!!
```

later you call

```
example_result = model.predict(example_batch) #model.summary() returns None
```

and python tells you

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'predict'

This is because you reassigned `model` in cell 11 to, well, nothing. You should remove the `model =` in cell 11 and your code will run perfectly!

redo cell 11 to read:

```
 model.summary()
```